# A summation similar to Vandermonde identity

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, summation-method

I met an identity, similar to Vandermonde's identity, but not sure how to prove:

$$\sum_{j=0}^k{k \choose j}{\frac{1}{2}j \choose n}(-1)^{n+k-j}=\frac{k}{n}(-1)^k2^{k-2n}{2n-k-1 \choose n-1}, \ n \geq k \geq0.$$

You may find this identity in Section 6 of "2018The computation of the probability density and distribution functions for some families of random variables by means of the Wynn-p accelerated Post-Widder formula" and Appendix of "2007Bayesian nonparametric estimation of the probability of discovering new species".

I cannot see how to apply Vandermonde's identity here, although they are similar.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there any restriction on $k$ in terms of $n$?

Comment: Thanks. I have added it into the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We seek to show that

$$\sum_{j=0}^k {k\choose j} {j/2\choose n} (-1)^{n-j} =
\frac{k}{n} 2^{k-2n} {2n-k-1\choose n-1}$$

where $n\ge k\ge 0.$ Here we have removed the factor $(-1)^k$ which is
present on both sides. We get for the even component

$$\sum_{p=0}^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor} 
{k\choose 2p} {p\choose n} (-1)^{n} = 0$$

because $n\gt p$ and $p\ge 0.$ This leaves the odd component

$$- (-1)^{n} \sum_{p=0}^{\lfloor (k-1)/2 \rfloor} 
{k\choose 2p+1} {p+1/2\choose n}.$$

Now we have

$${p+1/2\choose n} = \frac{1}{n!} \prod_{q=0}^{n-1} (p+1/2-q)
= \frac{1}{2^n n!} \prod_{q=0}^{n-1} (2p+1-2q)
\\ = \frac{1}{2^n n!} \prod_{q=0}^{p} (2p+1-2q)
\prod_{q=p+1}^{n-1} (2p+1-2q)
\\ = \frac{1}{2^n n!} \frac{(2p+2)!}{2^{p+1} (p+1)!}
(-1)^{n-p-1} \prod_{q=p+1}^{n-1} (2q-2p-1)
\\ = \frac{1}{2^n n!} \frac{(2p+2)!}{2^{p+1} (p+1)!}
(-1)^{n-p-1} \frac{(2n-2p-2)!}{2^{n-p-1} (n-p-1)!}
\\ = \frac{(-1)^{n-p-1} (2n)!}{2^{2n} n!^2}
{2n\choose 2p+2}^{-1} {n\choose p+1}
\\ = \frac{(-1)^{n-p-1}}{2^{2n}} {2n\choose n}
{2n\choose 2p+2}^{-1} {n\choose p+1}.$$

where $p\lt n.$ It will be helpful to re-write this as

$$\frac{p+1}{n} \frac{(-1)^{n-p-1}}{2^{2n}} {2n\choose n}
{2n-1\choose 2p+1}^{-1} {n\choose p+1}
\\ = \frac{(-1)^{n-p-1}}{2^{2n}} {2n\choose n}
{2n-1\choose 2p+1}^{-1} {n-1\choose p}.$$

We thus get for our sum

$$\frac{1}{2^{2n}} {2n\choose n}
\sum_{p=0}^{\lfloor (k-1)/2 \rfloor} (-1)^p {k\choose 2p+1}
{2n-1\choose 2p+1}^{-1} {n-1\choose p}.$$

Now observe that

$${k\choose 2p+1} {2n-1\choose 2p+1}^{-1}
= \frac{k!}{(k-2p-1)!} \frac{(2n-2p-2)!}{(2n-1)!}
\\ = {2n-1\choose k}^{-1} {2n-2p-2\choose k-2p-1}.$$

This yields for the sum

$$\frac{1}{2^{2n}} {2n\choose n} {2n-1\choose k}^{-1}
\sum_{p=0}^{\lfloor (k-1)/2 \rfloor} 
(-1)^p {2n-2p-2\choose k-2p-1} {n-1\choose p}.$$

Now to treat the remaining sum we have

$$[z^{k}] (1+z)^{2n-2} \sum_{p=0}^{\lfloor (k-1)/2 \rfloor}
(-1)^p z^{2p+1} (1+z)^{-2p} {n-1\choose p}.$$

The coefficient extractor enforces the upper limit
$\lfloor (k-1)/2\rfloor \ge p$ so we may continue with

$$[z^{k}] (1+z)^{2n-2} \sum_{p\ge 0}
(-1)^p z^{2p+1} (1+z)^{-2p} {n-1\choose p}
\\ = [z^{k}] (1+z)^{2n-2} z \left(1-\frac{z^2}{(1+z)^2}\right)^{n-1}
\\ = [z^{k}] z (1+2z)^{n-1}.$$

This means for $k=0$ the sum is zero. For $k\ge 1$ we get
including the factor in front

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{2^{2n}} {2n\choose n} {2n-1\choose k}^{-1}
{n-1\choose k-1} 2^{k-1}.}$$

To simplify this we expand the binomial coefficients

$$\frac{1}{2^{2n-k+1}} 
\frac{(2n)!\times k! \times (2n-1-k)! \times (n-1)!}
{n! \times n! \times (2n-1)! \times (k-1)! \times (n-k)!}
\\ = \frac{1}{2^{2n-k+1}} 
\frac{(2n)\times k \times (2n-1-k)!}
{n \times n! \times (n-k)!}
\\ = \frac{1}{2^{2n-k}} 
\frac{k \times (2n-1-k)!}
{n! \times (n-k)!}.$$

This yields at last

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{2^{2n-k}} 
\frac{k}{n} {2n-1-k\choose n-1}.}$$

Comment: Wow, beautiful. May I ask how can you make it? It is not obvious at all.

Comment: Experience with binomial sums. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[4px,#ffd]{\sum_{j = 0}^{k}{k \choose j}{j/2 \choose n}
\pars{-1}^{n + k - j}} =
\pars{-1}^{n + k}\sum_{j = 0}^{k}{k \choose j}\pars{-1}^{j}
\bracks{z^{n}}\pars{1 + z}^{\, j/2}
\\[5mm] &\ =
\pars{-1}^{n + k}\bracks{z^{n}}\sum_{j = 0}^{k}{k \choose j}
\pars{-\root{1 + z}}^{j} =
\pars{-1}^{n + k}\bracks{z^{n}}\pars{1 - \root{1 + z}}^{k}
\end{align}
The last expresion *vanishes out* whenever $\ds{n < k}$ because $\ds{\pars{1 - \root{1 + z}}^{k} \sim
\pars{-1/2}^{k}\,\color{red}{z^{k}}}$ as $\ds{\verts{z}\ \to\ 0}$.
Then,
$$
\bbox[4px,#ffd]{\sum_{j = 0}^{k}{k \choose j}{j/2 \choose n}
\pars{-1}^{n + k - j}} =
\pars{-1}^{n + k}\bracks{n \geq k}
\oint_{\mathcal{C}}
{\pars{1 - \root{1 + z}}^{k} \over z^{n + 1}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
$$
$\ds{\mathcal{C}}$ is a key-hole contour which take full advantage of the $\ds{\root{1 + z}}$ principal branch-cut along
$\ds{\left(-\infty,-1\right]}$:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[4px,#ffd]{\sum_{j = 0}^{k}{k \choose j}{j/2 \choose n}
\pars{-1}^{n + k - j}}
\\[5mm] = &
\pars{-1}^{n + k}\bracks{n \geq k}\left[%
\int_{-\infty}^{-1}{\pars{1 - \ic\root{-1 - x}}^{k} \over
x^{n + 1}}\,{\dd x \over 2\pi\ic}\right.
\\[2mm] &\ \phantom{\pars{-1}^{n + k}\bracks{n \geq k}}
+ \left.\int_{-1}^{-\infty}{\pars{1 + \ic\root{-1 - x}}^{k} \over
x^{n + 1}}\,{\dd x \over 2\pi\ic}\right]
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{-1}^{n + k}\bracks{n \geq k}\left[%
\int_{1}^{\infty}{\pars{1 - \ic\root{x - 1}}^{k} \over
\pars{-1}^{n + 1}\, x^{n + 1}}\,{\dd x \over 2\pi\ic}\right.
\\[2mm] &\ \phantom{\pars{-1}^{n + k}\bracks{n \geq k}}
-\left.\int_{1}^{\infty}
{\pars{1 + \ic\root{x - 1}}^{-k} \over
\pars{-1}^{n + 1}\, x^{n + 1}}\,{\dd x \over 2\pi\ic}\right]
\\[5mm] = &\
{\pars{-1}^{k} \over \pi}\,\bracks{n \geq k}
\,\Im\int_{1}^{\infty}
{\pars{1 + \ic\root{x - 1}}^{k} \over x^{n + 1}}\,\dd x
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
With $\ds{x = \sec^{2}\pars{\theta}}$:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[4px,#ffd]{\sum_{j = 0}^{k}{k \choose j}{j/2 \choose n}
\pars{-1}^{n + k - j}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{2\pars{-1}^{k} \over \pi}\,\bracks{n \geq k}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\cos^{2n - k - 1}\pars{\theta}
\sin\pars{\theta}\sin\pars{k\theta}\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] = &\
{\pars{-1}^{k} \over \pi}\,\bracks{n \geq k}
\pars{I_{2n - k - 1,1 - k} - I_{2n - k -1,1 + k}}
\label{2}\tag{2}
\\[5mm] &\ \mbox{where}\quad
I_{\ell,m} \equiv
\Re\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{\ell}\pars{\theta}
\expo{\ic m\theta}\dd\theta
\end{align}

---

$\ds{\large I_{\ell m}\ Evaluation:}$
\begin{align}
I_{\ell,m} & \equiv
\Re\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{\ell}\pars{\theta}
\expo{\ic m\theta}\dd\theta
\\[5mm] & =
\left.\Re\int_{\theta\ =\ 0}^{\theta\ =\ \pi/2}
\pars{z + 1/z \over 2}^{\ell}z^{m}\,
{\dd z \over \ic z}\right\vert_{\ z\ =\ \exp\pars{\ic\theta}}
\\[5mm] & =
\left.{1 \over 2^{\ell}}\,\Im\int_{\theta\ =\ 0}^{\theta\ =\ \pi/2}
\pars{1 + z^{2}}^{\ell}\, z^{m -\ell - 1}\,
\dd z\,\,\right\vert_{\ z\ =\ \exp\pars{\ic\theta}}
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\sim}\,\,\,
-\,{1 \over 2^{\ell}}\,\Im\int_{1}^{\epsilon}
\pars{1 - y^{2}}^{\ell}\, \expo{\ic\pars{m - \ell - 1}\pi/2}
y^{m -\ell - 1}\,\ic\,\dd y
\\[2mm] & \phantom{ \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\sim}\,\,\,}
-\,{1 \over 2^{\ell}}
\Im\int_{\pi/2}^{0}\epsilon^{m - \ell - 1}
\expo{\ic\pars{m - \ell - 1}\theta}
\epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}\ic\,\dd \theta
\\[5mm] & =
{\sin\pars{\bracks{m - \ell}\pi/2} \over 2^{\ell}\pars{m - \ell}}
\int_{y\ =\ \epsilon}^{y\ =\ 1}
\pars{1 - y^{2}}^{\ell}\,\dd\pars{y^{m -\ell}}
\\[2mm] & 
+ {\epsilon^{m - \ell} \over 2^{\ell}}\,
{\sin\pars{\bracks{m - l}\pi/2} \over m - \ell}
\\[5mm] & =
{\sin\pars{\bracks{m - \ell}\pi/2} \over 2^{\ell}\pars{m - \ell}}
\braces{-\epsilon^{m - \ell}
-\int_{\epsilon}^{1}
y^{m -\ell}\bracks{\ell\pars{1 - y^{2}}^{\ell - 1}\pars{-2y}}
\,\dd y}
\\[2mm] & 
+ {\epsilon^{m - \ell} \over 2^{\ell}}\,
{\sin\pars{\bracks{m - \ell}\pi/2} \over m - \ell}
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\large\to}\,\,\,
{\ell\sin\pars{\braces{m - \ell}\pi/2} \over
2^{\ell - 1}\pars{m - \ell}}
\int_{0}^{1}y^{m - \ell + 1}\pars{1 - y^{2}}^{\ell - 1}\,\dd y
\\[5mm] & =
{\ell\sin\pars{\braces{m - \ell}\pi/2} \over
2^{\ell}\pars{m - \ell}}
\int_{0}^{1}y^{m/2 - \ell/2}\,\pars{1 - y}^{\ell - 1}\,\dd y
\\[5mm] & =
{\ell\sin\pars{\bracks{m - \ell}\pi/2} \over
2^{\ell}\pars{m - \ell}}\,
{\Gamma\pars{m/2 - \ell/2 + 1}\Gamma\pars{\ell} \over
\Gamma\pars{m/2 + \ell/2 + 1}}
\\[5mm] & =
{\ell\sin\pars{\bracks{m - \ell}\pi/2} \over
2^{\ell}\pars{m - \ell}}\,
{\Gamma\pars{\ell} \over
\Gamma\pars{m/2 + \ell/2 + 1}}\,
{\pi \over
\sin\pars{\pi\bracks{\ell/2 - m/2}}\Gamma\pars{\ell/2 - m/2}}
\end{align}
Then,
\begin{align}
I_{\ell,m} & \equiv
\Re\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{\ell}\pars{\theta}
\expo{\ic m\theta}\dd\theta =
\bbx{\large{\pi \over 2^{\ell + 1}}{\ell \choose m/2 + \ell/2}}
\label{3}\tag{3}
\\ &
\end{align}

---

With (\ref{2}) and (\ref{3}):
\begin{align}
&\bbox[4px,#ffd]{\sum_{j = 0}^{k}{k \choose j}{j/2 \choose n}
\pars{-1}^{n + k - j}} =
{\pars{-1}^{k} \over \pi}\,\bracks{n \geq k}
\pars{I_{2n - k - 1,1 - k} - I_{2n - k - 1,1 + k}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{\pars{-1}^{k} \over \pi}\bracks{n \geq k}\bracks{%
{\pi \over 2^{2n - k}}{2n - k - 1 \choose n - k} -
{\pi \over 2^{2n - k}}{2n - k - 1 \choose n}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{\pars{-1}^{k} \over 2^{2n - k}}\bracks{n \geq k}\bracks{%
{2n - k - 1 \choose n - 1} - {2n - k - 1 \choose n}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{\pars{-1}^{k} \over 2^{2n - k}}\bracks{n \geq k}\braces{%
{2n - k - 1 \choose n - 1} -
{1 \over n}\bracks{{\pars{2n - k - 1} \over \pars{n - 1}!
\pars{n - k}!}}\pars{n - k}}
\\[5mm] \implies &\
\bbox[15px,#ffd,border:2px groove navy]{%
\sum_{j = 0}^{k}{k \choose j}{j/2 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n + k - j} =
\bracks{n \geq k}{\pars{-1}^{k} \over 2^{2n - k}}\,{k \over n}
{2n - k - 1 \choose n - 1}} \\ &
\end{align}